# Adding a new node to my linked list stack updates all my old nodes to the new node

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, stack

When I insert a string into my stack, it adds it but also changes all the previous elements as well.

```
void push(linkedList *ll,char *item) {
node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
if (ll->size == 0) {
    newNode->value = item;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    ll->head = newNode;
    ll->tail = newNode;
    ll->size++;
}
else {
    newNode->value = item;
    newNode->next = ll->head;
    ll->head = newNode;
    ll->size++;
}
}


int main() {
linkedList* stack = init();
int scan = 1;
char * p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
while (scan = 1) {
    scanf("%1s", p);
    if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9') {
        push(stack, p);
        print(stack);
    }
}

WINPAUSE;
}
```

The output looks something like this:

*insert 5*

5

*insert 7*

7 --> 7

*insert 8*

8 --> 8 --> 8

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same pointer every time.  You allocated that memory once, and continually replace its contents.  Since each node in the list holds the same pointer value, traversing the list will give you back the most recently input data, including if the data was not even in the valid range.

The most appropriate solution (of many options) is probably to do one of these things:

- copy the data by allocating new memory for it when you push an item
- store the data as a `char` value instead of a pointer, since you're only holding one character at a time (if this is appropriate for your task)

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. I was planning on storing more than one value once I figured this out. Is there an easy way to fix this while still passing through strings?

Comment: Yeah.  Like I said, copy the data.  That means `malloc` enough memory for it, and use `memcpy` or `strcpy` to copy into the new location.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `newNode->value = item`, which stores in your nodes always a pointer to the same memory location `p` reserved outside your `push` and overwritten with new content again and again. To overcome this, write `newNode->value = strdup(item)` in order to copy the content. Don't forget to free it later on. If `strdup` is not available, you can easily replace it with `newNode->value = malloc(strlen(item)+1);strcpy(newNode->value, item)`.

Comment: Thanks alot, this was a huge help.